# Ubuntu gray/foggy screen after sleep mode

Tags: 20.04, suspend

When I start my system after sleep mode, the entire screen becomes gray/foggy. I cannot recover from this point. The only solution is to power off by holding down the power key and then restart. I'm attaching here image of the screen:
[image]

**EDIT**

Sometimes this problem also happens when I first turn on the computer. After submitting password for the account, the screen becomes like shown in above image. After restarting and resubmitting the password, it behaves normally. I'm worrying that this issue will become persistent at one point and I will totally lose access to my system...